# Nuances between the prepositions "при" and "с" in "при таком отношении к учебе" vs "с таким отношением к учебе"

Tags: словоупотребление, предлоги

> Как ни странно, но даже **при таком отношении** к учебе, я умудрился сдать все экзамены за второе учебное полугодие.
>
> {vs}: Как ни странно, но даже **с таким отношением** к учебе, я умудрился сдать все экзамены за второе учебное полугодие.

From an English speaker's perspective, it is tempting to opt for the preposition "с" to express the idea of "**with** such attitude towards ...". In this context, French, Italian and German also use the *with* prepositions: "avec/con/mit".

I wonder if it is more common in Russian to choose the preposition "при". How are these two nuanced?

Answer (score 3):

If **с** is **with,** then **при** is **given.** “При”, the more official-sounding of the two, just states some condition, while “с” implies closer ties to the speaker.

The sentences given sound 99% equivalent because “отношение к учебе” is internal to the student anyway. But compare:

> Не могу работать при таком свете — anyone could say this to complain about the workplace being poorly lit.
>
> Не могу работать с таким светом — while this usage could be synonymous with the above in principle, this heavily implies that light is an essential part of the work, e. g. a photographer could say this.

Comment: So generally, "при" is more objective and "с" is more subjective?

Comment: @Alone-zee I would say “при” is more external and “с” is more internal.